# How to select area Yandex-Maps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer, yandex, yandex-maps

Good day. There was a need to show the area - polygon using Yandex Maps. 
Through touchesBegan / Moved / Ended I make UIBezierPath. Next I add CAShapeLayer to the map
[[self.mapView layer] addSublayer: self.shapeLayer];

It's all good, but when I'm trying to zoom or drag map, shape is standing at the same position.
I've found it's structure:
UIView
|-YXScrollView
|-ImageView

I suppose it's needed to add shapeLayer to scrollView, but it's hidden variable and I don't know how to get access to it.[image]